# Options route on express has weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, web

Here's the thing, i have this route on a node server using express (4.X) and when i do request's using the http options method sometimes works and returns 405 and the following it returns me a 200 and the routes allowed to call, anyone else facing the same issue?. I do the request from postman.

```
 app.options("/*", function(req, res, next){
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, 
    Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
    res.sendStatus(405);
 });
```

Comment: There seems to be a contradiction here. Why are you sending a 405 but setting OPTIONS as allowed with `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');`? What is the desired behaviour? Are you trying to disallow the OPTIONS method?

Comment: Yes, im trying to disallow the OPTIONS method, and i allow it but sending a 405 as response.

Comment: it seems to be a cache issue of a previous version on a docker container. I created another and deleted the orphan container and it worked. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a cache issue of a previous version on docker container. I created another, deleted the orphan container and worked as it supose to.